# What design pattern to use for configurable output of a concatenation of different primitive types in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, io

Let's say you have a C++ application. This C++ application computes various physical properties during a simulation run. These properties can be of type int or double.

The user of this program/library now has the ability to configure, which of these properties should be output into which file.

What I am looking for is a solution, that is both readable, reasonable and performant.

In the following, I sketch a possible solution, and afterwards list its drawbacks:

```
enum ComputedValues {
      STEP = 0,
      TIMESTEP = 1,
      TIME = 2,
      VOLUME = 3,
      PRESSURE = 4,
      TEMPERATURE = 5 // there would be more, of course
};

const std::array<std::string, 6> ComputedValuesNames = {
      "Step",        "TimeStep",    "Time",        "Volume",      "Pressure",
      "Temperature"
};

struct OutputConfig {
       std::vector<ComputedValues> values;
       std::string file;
       int outputEvery;
};

// then, the Simulator class would have methods
void addOutputConfig(OutputConfig conf);
void addAverageOutputConfig(OutputConfig conf);
// to configure what to output when

// finally, the actual simulation procedure would do something like:
std::array<double, 6> values = {
          static_cast<double>(step + initialStep + 1),
          dt,
          initialTime + static_cast<double>(step + 1) * dt,
          this->box.getVolume(),
          pressure + kineticPressureTerm,
          temperature;
for (OutputConfig conf : outputConfigurations) {
       for (ComputedValues val : conf.values) {
              outputBuffer += std::to_string(values[val]) + "\t";
       }
}
// and similar for averaging these values.
```

Pros:

- readable
- performant (just indexing into an array)

Cons:

- all values are double

Alternatives and why they do not quite match my dreams:

- Using a switch/case for all the properties: long and repeated code, as well as requiring copy-paste for the averaging vs. the "normal" output
- Abstract the values away into their own classes: feels overkill
- Separating into `ComputedIntValues` and `ComputedDoubleValues`: might be the most close to what I do above without the drawback, but feels like an unnecessary overhead for the user

In a Python program, it could be a simple key into a `dict`. What would be the best way to reach the objective listed above in C++?

Comment: C++ is strongly typed compile time, so limits are clear and compiler can optimise better.  If you want run-time to decide between types in C++ then you need a type that can hold any of possible alternatives, for example std::variant<int, double>. From there you will get also efficiency penalties.